# In $\mathbb{R}^2$, u orthogonal to v, v orthogonal to w => u parallel to w

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Given $u,v,w\in\mathbb{R^2}$ non-zero vectors. If $u\perp v$ amd $v\perp w$, then $u\parallel w$.

I think this question might be stupid but I couldn't prove it using only algebra. Can someone please help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: Rotate the frame so that $u = a\hat{i}$ for some non-zero $a \in \mathbb R$. Then necessarily $v = b\hat{j}$ for some $b \neq 0$ and $w = c\hat{i}$. Hence $u$ and $w$ are parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u = (a,b) \to u\perp v \Rightarrow v = (-kb,ka)$.

$v \perp w \Rightarrow w = (-m(ka),m(-kb)) = -km(a,b) = (-km)u \Rightarrow u \parallel w$

Comment: The first line was what I needed. Using it I could prove that $v=\left(\frac{-u_2}{u_1}v_2,v_2\right)$, which led to $w=\left(w_1,\frac{w_1u1}{u_2}\right)\Longrightarrow w = \frac{w_1}{u_1}u$. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  It follows from your hypothesis that $u,v$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Write $w$ as a linear combination of $u$ and $v$ and use orthogonality to show the coefficient of $v$ is zero.