# Parallelism condition in an inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, vectors, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

As we can see in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113957/in-mathbbr2-u-orthogonal-to-v-v-orthogonal-to-w-u-parallel-to-w), if $u, v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are such that $u \perp v$ and $v \perp w$ then $u$ and $w$ are  parallels. This occurs in inner product spaces? More precisely:

**Question.** Let $H=(H,(\cdot, \cdot))$ be an inner product space and $u,v,w \in H$ such that
$$
(u,v)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad (v,w)=0,
$$
then  $u= \alpha \cdot w$, for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$? If so, how to prove?

I don't see how to prove, since in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we use the fact that $\{u,v\}$  forms a basis, the we can use the orthogonality condition in order to obtain the desired. But how to recover the basis concept in $H$, since we might have that $\text{dim}(H)=\infty$.

Comment: This is only true in a two-dimensional space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This clearly need not be true in higher dimensions. In $\Bbb R^3$, take

$$u = (1,0,0)  \qquad v = (0,1,0) \qquad w = (0,0,1)$$

with the usual inner product.